# WCF in windows phone security transport

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

WP supports only basicHttpBinding. My app sends sensitive data through WCF and store them in DB. Data are sent as plain text and this is inacceptable. I found some solutions but it isn't working. I've set securityMode to Transport but I've got exception. Here is my web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="baseBinding" >
          <security mode="Transport" />
      </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="TestWCF.WcfNotificationService.WcfNotificationService">
    <endpoint address="base" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="baseBinding"
      contract="TestWCF.WcfNotificationService.IWcfNotificationService" />
    <host>
      <timeouts openTimeout="00:05:00" />
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

when I update service reference in client I get error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Could you help me, what I have to do?
Thanks